# Java Casting in Method Overloading

Tags: java, casting, overloading

I have the methods overloading such as:

```
 public int sum1(int a, int b)
{
    int c= a+b; 
    System.out.println("The method1");
    return c; 
}
public float sum1(int a, float b)
{
    float c=  a+b;
    System.out.println("The method2");
    return c; 
}
public double sum1(float a, float b)
{
    double c=  (double) a+b;
    System.out.println("The method3");
    return c; 
}
```

From the main method, suppose we have

```
 double x=10.10f;
 double y=10.20f;
```

the apparent type for x and y is double, but the actual type is float. when I call

```
System.out.println(" the output is :"+cc.sum1(x,y));
```

the error in the compile-time.

```
The method sum1(int, int) in the type Class is not applicable for the arguments double, double).
```

where it should go to sum1 (i.e. method3) by casting double to float

Comment: I don't even see any `?`.

Comment: *“the apparent type for x and y is double, but the actual type is float”* – No, the type is just `double`.  Primitive types are not polymorphic.  `float` is not a subclass of `double` and even if it were: overload resolution operates on the *static* types.  Also, your second overload is superfluous.  Just let the compiler implicitly convert the `int` to a `float` upon invocation.

Comment: @5gon12eder: Is `int` to `float` a lossless conversion?

Comment: @Thilo Yes, it is.  `long` to `float` is not, however.

Comment: How can this be? Aren't both 32 bit types? How can `float` store all possible `int` values and then some?

Comment: @Thilo Sorry, you are right.  `int` to `double` is lossless but `int` to `float` cannot be for the reason you mention.  The implicit conversion still takes place, however.  I'll look up where this is defined.

Comment: It seems they've simply defined it to be lossless / widening.  [§ 5.1.2 JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2): *“A widening primitive conversion from `int` to `float`, or from `long` to `float`, or from `long` to `double`, may result in loss of precision - that is, the result may lose some of the least significant bits of the value. In this case, the resulting floating-point value will be a correctly rounded version of the integer value, using IEEE 754 round-to-nearest mode.”*

Answer (score 11):

TL;DR version of this answer:

- Variables of primitive types never have a different type at execution-time to their compile-time. (A `double` is always a `double`, never a `float`, etc.)
- Overload resolution (picking which method signature is used) is performed using the compile-time types of expressions
- Method implementation of the picked signature is performed using the execution-time type of the target of the method call

---

> the apparent type for x and y is double, but the actual type is float

No, it's not. You've just got a conversion from the assigned `float` literals to `double` values. The *actual values* are `double`.

Primitives don't work like objects - there's no idea of an `int` value still being an `int` inside a `double` variable, for example.

It's simpler to take an example with integer types. Suppose we have:

```
byte b = 100;
int x = b;
```

The value of `x` is the 32-bit integer representing the value 100. It doesn't "know" that it was originally assigned from a `byte` value... there just happened to be a conversion from `byte` to `int` at the point of assignment.

Compare that with *reference* types:

```
String x = "hello";
Object y = x;
```

Here, the value of `y` really *is* a reference to a `String` object. That type information is preserved precisely because there's a whole object that can contain it, and because the value of the variable itself is only a reference. (The bits themselves don't need to change as part of the assignment - in a simple VM at least, they'll be the exact same bits in `x` and `y`, because they're referring to the same object.)

Even in that case, however, overload resolution occurs based on the *compile-time* type of the arguments, not their actual values at execution time. The only way that the execution-time type of a variable gets involved is with *overriding* based on the target of a method call. So if we have:

```
Foo f = new X();
Foo g = new Y();
Foo h = new Z();

f.someMethod(g, h);
```

... then the compiler will look for a method in `Foo` which has two `Foo` parameters (or `Object` or other superclasses/interfaces) - the actual types of the objects involved are irrelevant. At execution time, however, if that method has been overridden in `X`, then that override will be called due to the execution-time type of the object `f`'s value refers to.

Comment: @Thilo: True. Will add something about that.

Comment: @TheLostMind: yes, the method signature is chosen at compile time. But not just checked, that signature will then be used (even if at run-time a "better" one happens to be around).

Comment: @Thilo: See if my edit is enough - let me know if you want me to go into more detail. (I'm slightly reluctant to given that the question is only talking about primitives.)

Answer (score 3):

Casting double to float may cause loss of data, since it's a narrowing conversion, and is therefore not done automatically by the compiler. You'll have to cast the variables to float explicitly if you want it to take place.

Answer (score 1):

No, the actual type of the variables is `double`. The type of the constants that you're assigning to that `double` variable, which get promoted on assignment, is `float`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add new function: public double sum1(double a, double b). It will solve your problem. 
And also, this kind of casting will cause loss of data.

Answer (score 0):

Floats are funny that way.. they always try to convert to doubles automatically.  This code compiles, with floats at every turn.

```
    public class wood {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        float x = 10.1f;
        float y = 10.2f;
        System.out.println("Sum of x and y = " + sum1((float)x, (float)y));
    }
    public static float sum1(float x, float y) {
        return (float)((float)x+(float)y);
    }
}
```

edit;  note that using a cast operator outside of parenthesis will cast after what is inside of the parenthesis has computed.  So;

```
System.out.println((int)(50.5 + 50.7));
```

will print out 101.

Within java, some data conversions are automatic, and others require cast operators.. simply put, java will automatically make widening conversions, while you will have to use a cast operator for narrowing conversions.

The hierarchy of primitive data types is as follows:

byte      //1 byte  (-128 through 127)

short     //2 bytes (over 32,000 give/take from 0)

int       //4 bytes (over 2billion give/take from 0)

long      //8 bytes (over 9 quintillion (10^18) give/take from 0)

float     //4 bytes (holds 7 decimal places)

double    //8 bytes (holds 15 decimal places)

java will not make narrowing conversions automatically, because then data is at risk of being lost.  Both byte and short will become ints automatically.

```
short s = 5;
byte b = 5;
short sum = s + b;  //this will cause an error!
```

s and b automatically make a widening conversion to an int, and an int cannot be assigned to a short without a cast operator.

```
short sum = (short)(s + b);
```

would be needed.

Comment: Glad it makes sense.  Knowing how java does it's data-type conversions is important.